# How to install PySide2 on RaspberryPi?

Tags: python, qt, pip

i use this command to install PySide2:

```
$ pip3 install pyside2
```

and i get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyside2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyside2
```

how i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --upgrade python3-pyside2.qt3dcore python3-pyside2.qt3dinput python3-pyside2.qt3dlogic python3-pyside2.qt3drender python3-pyside2.qtcharts python3-pyside2.qtconcurrent python3-pyside2.qtcore python3-pyside2.qtgui python3-pyside2.qthelp python3-pyside2.qtlocation python3-pyside2.qtmultimedia python3-pyside2.qtmultimediawidgets python3-pyside2.qtnetwork python3-pyside2.qtopengl python3-pyside2.qtpositioning python3-pyside2.qtprintsupport python3-pyside2.qtqml python3-pyside2.qtquick python3-pyside2.qtquickwidgets python3-pyside2.qtscript python3-pyside2.qtscripttools python3-pyside2.qtsensors python3-pyside2.qtsql python3-pyside2.qtsvg python3-pyside2.qttest python3-pyside2.qttexttospeech python3-pyside2.qtuitools python3-pyside2.qtwebchannel python3-pyside2.qtwebsockets python3-pyside2.qtwidgets python3-pyside2.qtx11extras python3-pyside2.qtxml python3-pyside2.qtxmlpatterns
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package python3-pyside2uic

Comment: @StraightFoward thanks. fixed.